# fully justify section heading

Tags: alignment

In international standards a standard layout is used. For my thesis I have to include a method using these standards. Therefore I would have to put long section headings fully justified while the second line also starts on the left and not on the indent of the section heading. I have read `\usepackage{ragged2e}` can be used to switch between text alignments in text but I don't know if this also renders the possibility to fully justify section heads.

The result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: headings are justified by default in most latex classes. but in your image I would expect just the 7.2 to be the inline heading of a default justified paragraph?

Comment: Dear David, thank you for your comment. How would I realise such an inline heading?

Comment: In 2002 I produced LaTeX code for typesetting ISO standard documents (try `texdoc iso` or `kpsewhich isov2.cls`). ISO's typesetting specifications might well have changed sine then but taking a look at the `isov2.cls` code might help you.

Comment: Dear Peter, thank you for your comment. Can I use this on a specific range of text?

Answer (score 1):

LateX headings are justified by default (which they should probably not be) but the image you show is not a justified *heading* but a normal justified paragraph but with a run-in heading with no title and just a number.

The standard classes start using run-in headings at the `\paragraph` level:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{} some text some text some text some text some text
 some text some text some text some text some text some text
 some text some text some text some text some text some text

\paragraph{} some text some text some text some text some text
 some text some text some text some text some text some text
 some text some text some text some text some text some text


\end{document}
```

But it looks like you want run-in subsections, there are several packages to adjust section formatting but it is easy enough tocopy the definition from `article.cls` and change the definition (flipping the sign of one argument changes from display to run-in)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {-1em}%{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}

\section{Zzzz}

\subsection{} some text some text some text some text some text
 some text some text some text some text some text some text
 some text some text some text some text some text some text

\subsection{} some text some text some text some text some text
 some text some text some text some text some text some text
 some text some text some text some text some text some text


\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, the text starts on the line beneath the heading. Maybe it's because my document class is report and not article?

Comment: it will work the same in report, take this answer and change article tp report, you may have some other package resetting it again. @JensVancoppenolle